# Using inputStream.getClass().getCanonicalName() but return null?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm using Android `HttpURLConnection` to do network downloading. Here is my code:

```
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://XXXXXXXXXX").openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        Log.d("Reflection",inputStream.getClass().getCanonicalName());

        int TOTAL_LEN = conn.getContentLength();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 8];
        int len = 0, total = 0;
        while (len != -1) {
            len = inputStream.read(buf);
            total += len;
            Log.d("Download Process:", total * 1.0 / TOTAL_LEN * 100 + "");
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Since `Inputstream` is a abstract class, I use reflection to show its implementation:`inputStream.getClass().getCanonicalName()`. But the result is null.

So I try `inputStream.getClass()` and the result is `class com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1`.

Why? How can I figure out the real implementation of the `inputstream` here?

---

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

The answer is `anonymous class`. I went through the Android source code and discovered it. The location is `/external/okhttp/okio/src/main/java/okio/RealBufferedSource.java` and the code is below:

```
public InputStream inputStream() {
  return new InputStream() {
  @Override
  public int read() throws IOException {
    if (closed) throw new IOException("closed");
    if (buffer.size == 0) {
      long count = source.read(buffer, Segment.SIZE);
      if (count == -1) return -1;
    }
    return buffer.readByte() & 0xff;
  }

  @Override
  public int read(byte[] data, int offset, int byteCount) throws IOException {
    if (closed) throw new IOException("closed");
    checkOffsetAndCount(data.length, offset, byteCount);

    if (buffer.size == 0) {
      long count = source.read(buffer, Segment.SIZE);
      if (count == -1) return -1;
    }

    return buffer.read(data, offset, byteCount);
  }

  @Override
  public int available() throws IOException {
    if (closed) throw new IOException("closed");
    return (int) Math.min(buffer.size, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {
    RealBufferedSource.this.close();
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return RealBufferedSource.this + ".inputStream()";
  }
};
}
```

Notice that this method returns a `new InputStream()` and it is anonymous.

Comment: I think `getClass()` is what you want.  The class is anonymous (that's what the `$1` means in the class name) so it doesn't have a canonical name.

Comment: @markspace Thanks for the information.

Comment: Why do you care what the implementation class is? It doesn't make any difference to you.

Comment: How about using `getName()` instead?

Comment: @EJP I need to modify the source code of InputStream, for some reasons.

Comment: @NannuoLei I tried, the result is `com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1`, and it's not what I want.

Comment: Then I don't quite get what you need. Could you explain further?

Comment: According to the Java documentation, getCanonicalName() "returns null if the underlying class does not have a canonical name (i.e., if it is a local or anonymous class or an array whose component type does not have a canonical name)."... so maybe what you're after is not even possible.

Comment: Yes...going through the source code reveals why it happens. It is due to an anonymous class. Problem solved, thx a lot.@NannuoLei

Comment: Solved, special thanks to @markspace and Nannuo Lei.